# Currency Settings

Tags: gnucash

I changed the currency in GnuCash settings from USD to SAR. Although my computer's regional settings are all set to English, GnuCash is displaying me arabic shorthand for SAR (رس). How to change it back to english SAR without changing the currency?

Thanks
Am using GnuCash 2.6.0 on Windows 7

[image]

Comment: Did you install it in Arabic? It may also use the relevant locale currency shortcut, so you can try and change that.

Comment: I installed in the standard English version. Still struggling with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to the main menu -> `Tools` -> `Security Editor`. In the window that opens, choose the "`CURRENCY`" list, find `SAR` there and double-click. You'll be able to edit the display symbol. You can change it to whatever you want.